# Input letter and displaying the corresponding output in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

Hello i am creating the assembly program that accepts a single character and display the alphabet . The requirements are (1) The input character should be displayed (2) The input of the single uppercase letter should be displayed the lowercase letter. (3) The alphabet should be displayed horizontal position and (3) Only the letter 'X' should be accepted as input.

I managed to let the program when input a uppercase character and displayed the alphabet in lowercase letter however, it displayed vertically position and also the displayed uppercase letter. I don't know to how figure out, Can somebody help me to on this topic... Thank you

```
.model small
.stack
.data
    input db "Input a Uppercase Character -> $"
.code
org 100h
start:
    main proc
        mov ax,03
        int 10h
        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax
        mov ah,9     
        lea dx, input
        int 21h
        mov ah,01
        int 21h
        mov dh,al
                mov ah,02
                mov dl,13
                int 21h
                mov dl,10
                int 21h
        mov al,dh
        mov bl,al
        cmp bl, 'a'
        jb main
        cmp bl, 'z'
        ja main
        mov dl,al
        sub dl,20h
        mov ah,02
        int 21h
        mov cx,26
        mov dh,dl
            letters:
                 mov bx,cx
                 call down
                 mov dl,dh
                 cmp dl,'Z'
                 je exit
                 inc dl
                 int 21h
                 mov dh,dl
                 mov cx,bx
            loop letters
        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
    main endp
            down proc
                mov dl,13
                int 21h
                mov dl,10
                int 21h
                ret
            down endp
            exit proc
                mov ah,4ch
                int 21h
            exit endp
end start
```

The output should be like this:
EVEN EVEN

Input: X

xyz

Comment: You case use an ASCII table to find out the relationship between upper and lower case letters (hint: the relative order of the letters is the same, so you only need to figure out how to transform one letter). I can't understand the other points, particularly, the fixed input (and thus output?) requirement.

Comment: "it displayed vertically" .. so stop outputting new-lines after each char. There's lot of redundancy in that code, for example you have exit proc, but inline the exit (exit proc is a bit overkill anyway), or you have "down" proc, yet you inline new-line output in other place anyway instead of calling down, etc... do you have some idea what these instruction does, or you just randomly copy lines from sources and hope it will work? It will not.